# What is the difference b/w != and <> comparison operator in python?

Tags: python, comparison, operators

Look in the following website:
  [TutorialPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm)

There under the heading of `Python Comparison Operators:`

You will see that it is written that `!=` is similar to `<>` operator
and even I tested this thing.

So what is the main difference between these two comparison operators?

Also there are documents that say they are similar, and not the same. Is there different criteria for the comparison for these two comparison operators?

Comment: and also there is no useful result on internet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 2.7, they're the same. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators):

> The comparison operators <> and != are alternate spellings of the same
>   operator. != is the preferred spelling; <> is obsolescent.

In 3.X, `<>` no longer exists.

Comment: In Python 3, `<>` can be (NOT recommended) turned-on at the expense of `!=` via `from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL`. This is sort of a joke easter egg though!

Answer (score 2):

According to [Expressions - Comparisons - Python 2.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> **The forms `<>` and `!=` are equivalent**; for consistency with C, `!=` is
>   preferred; where `!=` is mentioned below `<>` is also accepted. **The `<>`
>   spelling is considered obsolescent.**

And, `<>` is gone in Python 3.x. Don't use `<>` if possible.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the documentation, they are the same.<> is deprecated and was removed in Python 3, so you should use !=.